# Run Queries on Models without FK/Navigational Property

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Lets say that i have 2 models/entities in my website, User and Ticket.
User and Ticket have a one to many association (one user can have many tickets).

```
class User {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
}

class Ticket {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, the Ticket model doesn't contain any reference to the User model.

My question is how can i filter Tickets that belong to a specific user?
If the Ticket model had a reference to a User model, i could do:

```
IEnumerable<Ticket> tickets = context.Tickets.Where(t => t.User.Id == userId);
```

But without having a User object in the Ticket model, it's not possible.
I realize that i can just load the user that i want and then access its Tickets from its Model, but that would cost me in unnecessarily loading the User, i don't want to load the user, i just want to load its Tickets.

Thank you

**Update**

Lets say that each Ticket can have multiple sub Tickets:

```
class Ticket {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Children { get; set; }
}
```

And given a User id, i want to get all the tickets that belong to that user but aren't sub tickets (have no parent).

How can i do it without having a Parent property in the Ticket model?

And even if i have a Parent property in the Ticket model and i run this query:

```
var tickets = context.Where(u => u.Id == userId).SelectMany(u => u.Tickets).Where(t => t.Parent == null);
```

But from what i understand, due to lazy loading, the Parent property can be null either by being actually null in the database itself, or just because it hasn't loaded yet...

Comment: _But from what i understand, due to lazy loading, the Parent property can be null either by being actually null in the database itself, or just because it hasn't loaded yet..._ you are dealing with not-yet-executed query here, so you are not in the field of lazy loading yet. Your expression `t => t.Parent == null` will be translated into proper SQL (I assume we are talking about SQL-backed model).

Comment: @MichaelSagalovich what do you mean by SQL-backed model? my database runs on a Sql Server database.

Comment: that's what I assumed, ok.

Comment: @MichaelSagalovich Your answer really helped me, i though that it is a waste of resources to reference a navigational property (instead of foreign key) from linq queries, but now i understand that inside those queries the navigational properties aren't even loaded, everything is just translated into SQL.
Thank you for explaining it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is the tickets for a particular user:

```
var tickets = context.Users
    .Where(u => u.Id == userID)
    .SelectMany(u => u.Tickets);
```

Assuming that your model is database-backed, this will result in a single query that returns just a list of Ticket records.

---

For the additional test of "not a sub of other tickets" you would add another clause, like this:

```
var tickets = context.Users
    .Where(u => u.Id == userID)
    .SelectMany(u => u.Tickets)
    .Where(t => !context.Tickets.Any(t1 => t1.Children.Contains(t)));
```

Note that `Any` and `All` are similar, I just think that `Any` fits this one better.

Comment: One note here: this is technically the best thing you can do to solve your particular problem, but generally it might be a good option to additionally check if the user with given id exists, and this is doable in 1 DB query still: `var userTickets = context.Users.Where(u => u.Id == userID).Select(u => u.Tickets).FirstOrDefault();`, after which you can check if the result is null and perform relevant actions (Exception?).

Comment: @Corey thank you very much, i will adapt your answer.
I have updated my question, now every ticket can have multiple sub tickets and given a user id, i want to fetch all the tickets that belong to that user but aren't sub tickets.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying @Corey answer basing on the update (try it, I just wrote it without testing):

```
var tickets = context.Users
    .Where(u => u.Id == userID)
    .SelectMany(u => u.Tickets)
    .Where(t => context.Tickets.All(t1 => !t1.Children.Contains(t)));
```